# why am I not able to execute SQL query on my existing postgres database table?

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

for learning purpose I have migrated my database from SQLite to postgres recently with in my Django project, and it was successful.

I am able to connect to the DB through below command

```
sudo -u <username> psql -d <DB_name>;
```

I am able to list the tables including the schema:

```
\d
```

But when I tried to query simple select query it give below error:

```
select * from public.AUTHENTICATION_userprofile;
ERROR:  relation "public.authentication_userprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from public.AUTHENTICATION_userprofile;
```

Table details:

```
 Schema |               Name                |   Type   |  Owner
--------+-----------------------------------+----------+----------
 public | AUTHENTICATION_userprofile        | table    | postgres
 public | AUTHENTICATION_userprofile_id_seq | sequence | postgres
```

Any suggestions please.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have created the table with capital letters, Postgres will be case sensitive for this table and you would have to put double quotes in the query:

```sql
select * from public."AUTHENTICATION_userprofile";
```